# Animação com dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou estudando dependency properties em WPF. Em todos os artigos que leio é citada a utilização desse recurso nas animações, mas não consegui achar nenhuma aplicação.

Qual a vantagem de se utilizar uma dependency property se eu posso fazer as animações diretamente no wpf?